# Cassandra snitches: read procedure

Tags: cassandra

I'm currently reading the book "Cassandra, the definitive guide", and there is a passage that I don't really get:

> When Cassandra performs a read, it must contact a number of replicas
>   determined by the consistency level. In order to support the maximum
>   speed for reads, Cassandra selects a single replica to query for the
>   full object, and asks additional replicas for hash values in order to
>   ensure the latest version of the requested data is returned. The role
>   of the snitch is to help identify the replica that will return the
>   fastest, and this is the replica which is queried for the full data.

Sorry to ask a few grouped question, but since they are related to the same passage of text, I guess it would make sense to ask them together.

So, what is meant with consistency level?
As I understand, 1 replica (= partition?) is selected (how?) to fetch the data.
Then, 1 replica is used to check if this partition contains the latest data. But if you have e.g. multiple replicas, then how is it determined that this specific replica can be used to check for the latest data?
How does it work at all and, how can it be determined that it is not another replica that contains the latest data?

For example, r1 and r2 contain the same data. R3 contains the latest data. For example R1 is selected, checked against r2.
Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra has tunable [consistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntDataConsistencyTOC.html) - you can specify consistency level for operations - for [writes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntDataConsistencyTOC.html) this is how many write confirmations should be obtained before returning the write confirmation to client, and for [reads](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntClientRequestsRead.html) - how many replicas should be contacted to obtain data that should be returned to client.  Usually, the smaller consistency level leads to better performance (you don't wait for other nodes), but could lead to either data loss (if server is going down right after write), or to returning stale data (if replica is out of sync).

For example, you have replication factor 3 - in this case you'll have 3 copies of your data (replicas).  If you read with consistency level QUORUM, then you need to get data from 2 nodes. In this case, the node that handles read (coordinator) sends request for all data to one node, and digest request to another node(s). Digest is used to compare with actual data to find, if there is a difference of data between replicas.

I recommend to read the [DSE Architecture guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archTOC.html) to understand about consistency levels, read/write paths & overall how Cassandra works.

Talking about snitches, here is the quote from [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archSnitchesTOC.html):

> A snitch determines which datacenters and racks nodes belong to. Snitches inform the database about the network topology so requests are routed efficiently.

Based on information about replicas location, Cassandra is doing decision on what nodes should be contacted to fulfill requests - for example, don't read data from another data center if request is with consistency `LOCAL_...`, plus many other things.

Comment: So if I understand it right, depending on the chosen consistency level, you may not get the latest data given a replication factor 3 and consistency level QUORUM.

Comment: Yes, if you write at CL = 1... To make sure that data is consistent,  the sum of write and read CL should be bigger than RF... For example read and write at QUORUM...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the book explains further how the first replica is determined:

> The first replica will always be the node that claims the range in
>   which the token falls, but the remainder of the replicas are placed
>   according to the replication strategy (sometimes also referred to as
>   the replica placement strategy).

In addition and credit to the book, they also explain it well afterwards:

> For read queries, the consistency level specifies how many replica
>   nodes must respond to a read request before returning the data. For
>   write operations, the consis‐ tency level specifies how many replica
>   nodes must respond for the write to be reported as successful to the
>   client. Because Cassandra is eventually consistent, updates to other
>   replica nodes may continue in the background.
>
> The available consistency levels include ONE, TWO, and THREE, each of
>   which specify an absolute number of replica nodes that must respond to
>   a request. The QUORUM consis‐ tency level requires a response from a
>   majority of the replica nodes (sometimes expressed as “replication
>   factor / 2 + 1”). The ALL consistency level requires a response from
>   all of the replicas. We’ll examine these consistency levels and others
>   in more detail in Chapter 9.
>
> For both reads and writes, the consistency levels of ANY, ONE, TWO,
>   and THREE are con‐ sidered weak, whereas QUORUM and ALL are considered
>   strong. Consistency is tuneable in Cassandra because clients can
>   specify the desired consistency level on both reads and writes. There
>   is an equation that is popularly used to represent the way to achieve
>   strong consistency in Cassandra: R + W > N = strong consistency. In
>   this equation, R, W, and N are the read replica count, the write
>   replica count, and the replication fac‐ tor, respectively; all client
>   reads will see the most recent write in this scenario, and you will
>   have strong consistency.